# CITEMAHPLA Reverse Alphametic

Tags: lateral-thinking, alphametic

Attempt at a Reverse Alphametic puzzle with a mathematically correct equation:

**68053 + 2531 = 70584**

Replace all the numbers with English letters (same number: same letter, so totally 9 separate letters used) and create a correct word equation.( A five letter word plus a four letter word equals a five letter word). The word equation must make logical sense.

Try these clues if you find it very hard

> 1   My answer involves 3 vowels and 6 consonants
>
> 2   The answer is something that can be enjoyable as well as bad

Comment: Just to confirm: Your two "clues" are necessary requirements for finding the solution, is that correct? Also, in clue #2, when you say "the answer" could be enjoyable or bad, are you referring to one of the words, or all three words?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Making logical sense" is ill-defined. Here are several options that *sort of* make sense.

> GREAT+PATH=FEARS
>  CLAIM+TIME=FAILS
>  PLAIN+WINE=DAILY
>  GREAT+CATS=LEARN
>  OCEAN+WANT=BEACH
>  PERIL+FILM=CRIED
>  SLAIN+KING=DAILY
>  GREAT+MATH=LEARN (if not for the "3 vowels" thing, I'd say this is what you were looking for)
>  TRAIN+LINE=PEARS
>  DREAM+CAMP=TEARS
>  THOSE+USED=YOSHI

There are *hundreds* of others: just input `fhjec beca gjehd` into [quipqiup](https://quipqiup.com/). (After all, this is essentially a cryptogram with *very little* ciphertext, which makes it very difficult to solve except through pure luck.)

The likely answer you're looking for is either:

> **OCEAN + LAND = BEACH** or **OCEAN + SAND = BEACH**.

Answer (score 2):

I did exactly what Deusovi did. After scanning the screen for 3 vowel-phrases, I end up with:

> PLAIN WINE DAILY.
>  3 Vowels, 6 consonants? - ✓
>  Makes sense- ✓ (sort of)
>  Enjoyable and bad - ✓ (Enjoyable in short run, bad in the long term)